# Hibernate - Connection not closed in connection pool

Tags: hibernate, datasource, connection-pooling

I am using org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and I want to monitor the UNCLOSED connections.
What properties i have to set in hibernate config file?

Thanks.
Giovanni

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to update your log4j configuration so the c3p0 config is printed to your log file. Just set category com.mchange.v2.c3p0 to "info". I'm having great difficulty getting my c3p0 configuration file to be picked up, so maybe yours isn't being read either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is something supported by DBCP (if it is, maybe add a link to the documentation).

However, it should be possible using C3P0 and the following properties (see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813083/hibernate-c3p0-connection-leak/2816911#2816911)):

- [`unreturnedConnectionTimeout`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) (set it to a value greater than `0`)
- [`debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces) (set it to `true`)

You'll have to set them in the `c3p0.propeties` (see [Appendix C: Hibernate-specific notes](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific)).

Another option would be to use BoneCP.

But I wonder why you need this, I'm pretty sure Hibernate is not leaking connections.

Comment: I want found the connection that programmers didn't close.  I am using  C3P0 now and I have setted the two properties but it doesn't write anything!

Comment: Sorry.  I put the snippet of applicationContext.xml of Spring of connection parameters: <bean id="inteseDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"> ....<property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="30" /> 
<property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" /> I hope it logs the connections not closed by programmers but it doesn't it.